# Flask SQLAlchemy : How to Select from Existing MySQL Database?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I already have a database called testdatabase with a table called ScrapedBooks in MySQL Workbench and it goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ScrapedBooks(BookName VARCHAR(100) , Price VARCHAR(20), ImageLink VARCHAR(200), BookLink VARCHAR(200) )')
```

Now in Flask-SQLAlchemy, I want to retrieve it and show it on my own webpage, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it because almost all the tutorials wants you to create a new database.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql://root:******@localhost/testdatabase'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Where do I go from here?